# What is this capacitor for?

Tags: capacitor

I found this in a schematic on the web.  I don't understand the use of this capacitor.

[Link for the schematic.](https://ez.analog.com/cfs-filesystemfile/__key/communityserver-discussions-components-files/427/SCHEMATIC1---PAGE-4--CURRENT-OU.pdf?_=636824335456385849)

Capacitor:

[image]

Partial circuit diagram:

[image]

Comment: Show the rest of the circuit.  Where do the arrows go?

Comment: Did you ask a very similar question a few days ago?

Comment: i added the link to the schematic

Comment: @Andyaka no , i did not ask this question before

Comment: What a mess of a schematic.  It obscures as much as it explains.

Comment: @JRE i agree with you about the schematic, but it's not me who draw it so i can't explain it. 
I just found the capacitor connected between two power source and i didnt understand what's for

Comment: If I'd thought you had drawn the schematic I'd have been politer about it.  I had a look at the full schematic in the PDF, and gave up looking for where the ends of the capacitor go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer may be in the *layout* of the PCB. It is possible that some high frequency return current(s) need a path back to their source but the reference plane is split between 3V3 and 24V0.

The capacitor would "*stitch*" 3V3 and 24V0 at high frequencies to allow for the current(s) to return back. The downside is that now high frequency noise can also couple between the voltage rails.

[image]

https://www.protoexpress.com/blog/best-high-speed-pcb-routing-practices/